# Oracle Top-N query: are results guaranteed to be ordered?

Tags: sql, oracle

Most sources, including Oracle's own [Top-N Queries](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/top-n-queries) article, give syntax similar to the following for performing a Top-N query:

```
SELECT val
FROM (
    SELECT val
    FROM rownum_order_test
    ORDER BY val DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 5;
```

This is guaranteed to give the top 5 values; however, is it guaranteed to give them in the correct order? [This question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/82930/108612), citing [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_by), indicates otherwise:

> Although some database systems allow the specification of an ORDER BY clause in subselects or view definitions, the presence there has no effect.

Does this mean that the aforementioned code does not guarantee any ordering, and requires an additional `ORDER BY`, or is it an exceptional case?

```
SELECT val
FROM (
    SELECT val
    FROM rownum_order_test
    ORDER BY val DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM <= 5
ORDER BY val DESC;   -- Is this line necessary?
```

**Edit**: Assume that the outer query will be executed directly (not nested in another query). I'm posing this question because it feels like a glaring omission that none of the sources (including Oracle's) bothered to mention the need for the `ORDER BY`, despite that ordering would be intuitively expected from such top-n queries.

Comment: it requires an additional order by if you are trying to show the final result in a specific order. without it the first 5 rows would be returned in a random order which is as expected some times but not always.

Comment: Thanks @vkp, I feared as much. Although I find it suspicious that all of the sources neglect to point out this vital detail, given that one would intuitively expect the rows to be returned in sorted order when performing a top-n query.

Comment: using analytical functions like `row_number, rank, dense_rank` would give you guaranteed results.

Comment: No. If you want your results ordered (in Oracle), then use an order by. It's that simple.

Comment: The concept itself of "returning rows in the right order" doesn't make 100% sense. The outer query "doesn't know" how you will consume the rows (is it, itself, a subquery to be used in a join, a higher-level query, a WHERE clause?) As such, there is no "right order". If the way you consume the resulting rows is to display them on screen or write them to a file, and you need them in a specific order, you should use an additional ORDER BY. That's the theory. In practice, it is possible that Oracle, once it has already ordered the rows in the inner query, it will retrieve them in that order.

Comment: As far as I know, that is in fact the case in Oracle, but I personally don't like relying on it (on principle). The good news is that, by adding an ORDER BY to the outer query, you are only ordering 5 rows (or 1000 rows), which Oracle can do very quickly. And if in fact the rows ARE presented to it in "the right order" already, ordering them again (when it is not really needed) takes REALLY no time at all.

Comment: SQL is by definition **orderless** so if you always want the same order always you should use a `ORDER BY` clause in anny SQL server which speaks the SQL dialect not only in Oracle database.

Answer (score 1):

The order by clearly has an effect here, because if it did not then the query simply would not work to provide the top-n values.

There may well be cases where the optimiser can detect that there is no effect provided by an ORDER BY, and in such cases it might transform the query to remove the ORDER BY, but this is not one of those cases.

If your outer query does not re-order the rows, either explicitly or implicitly (through a join, perhaps), then I would be confident that in this case the order will be preserved.

Comment: I would assume the same, but I'd like to find some documentation of this behaviour before accepting it as definitive. Many people make the same assumption about the ordering of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` in .NET, which appears to be preserved in most cases, but then turns out [not to hold](https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/the-net-dictionary/) under certain circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

In older versions of ORACLE (8.0) you don't have the possibility to use ORDER BY clause in subquery. So, only for those of us who yet use some ancient versions, there is another way to deal with: The magic of UNION operator. UNION will sort the records by columns in the query:

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT EMP_NO, EMP_NAME FROM EMP_TABLE
UNION
SELECT 99999999999,'' FROM DUAL)
WHERE ROWNUM<=5;
```

where 99999999999 is bigger then all values in EMP_NO

Or, if you want to select TOP 5 salary employees with the highest 5 salaries:

```
SELECT EMP_NO, EMP_NAME, 99999999999999-TMP_EMP_SAL
FROM
(SELECT 99999999999999-EMP_SAL TMP_EMP_SAL, EMP_NO, EMP_NAME 
FROM EMP_TABLE
UNION
SELECT 99999999999999,0,'' FROM DUAL)
WHERE ROWNUM<=5;
```

Regards,
Virgil Ionescu